# Which character to escape for this to work in ~/.bashrc

Tags: command-line, bash, bashrc

I want to add this `iostat` command to my `.bashrc` and create an alias for it:

```
iostat -xk 2 $(findmnt -T ~ | awk 'END {print $2}')
```

I'm adding this to my `.bashrc`:

```
alias ios='iostat -xk 2 $(findmnt -T ~ | awk 'END {print $2}')'
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't work.

If I run the above `iostat` command in a terminal it works, but when I run the `ios` alias it no longer works.

And yes, I restart my shell every time.

Comment: FYI you can likely avoid the issue by telling findmnt to only output the information you actually want ex. `findmnt -no SOURCE -T ~` and dropping the pipe to awk altogether

Answer (score 9):

Use a function instead; the quoting is simpler:

```
ios () {
  iostat -xk 2 $(findmnt -T ~ | awk 'END {print $2}')
}
```

Answer (score 6):

```
alias ios='iostat -xk 2 $(findmnt -T ~ | awk 'END {print $2}')'
```

you can not use quotes inside quotes. Alternate between quote and doublequote is the easiest method. So this works:

```
$ alias ios="iostat -xk 2 $(findmnt -T ~ | awk 'END {print $2}')"
$
```

From edit:

> Note that although it works in this case (because `~` isn't going to move to a different block device in the meantime), the "soft" outer quotes cause the command substitution to be evaluated at definition time rather than dynamically on alias invocation

If you need single quotes you can glue them together using `'"'"'`:

```
$ alias ios='iostat -xk 2 $(findmnt -T ~ | awk '"'"'END {print $2}'"'"')'
$
```

Comment: It's working @Rinzwind , thank you !

Comment: Note that although it works *in this case* (because `~` isn't going to move to a different block device in the meantime), the "soft" outer quotes cause the command substitution to be evaluated at definition time rather than dynamically on alias invocation

Comment: Understood, thank you @steeldriver !

Comment: With the double quotes, the command substitution will run when you define the alias, not when you use it.

Answer (score 0):

Nested quotes are always trouble.

You can do it like this:

```
echo 'Hello '\'~\'' world'
```